# java.lang.NullPointerException in handling with FXML inside another FXML in Javafx

Tags: nullpointerexception, javafx, fxml

I have been trying to figure out how to deal with a FXML file in another FXML file. But I have an exception. :(
This is my inner FXML (NewInside.fxml in view package):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="305.0" prefWidth="360.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="controller.NewInsideController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="newBtn" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="202.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnClick" text="Button" />
      <TextField fx:id="newTxt" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="134.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="280.0" />
      <Label fx:id="newLbl" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="62.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="280.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is its controller (NewInsideController.java in controller package):

```
package controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class NewInsideController implements Initializable{

    @FXML public static Label newLbl;
    @FXML public static TextField newTxt;
    @FXML public static Button newBtn;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    @FXML
    private void btnClick(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("Button is clicked!");
        newLbl.setText(newTxt.getText());
    }

}
```

And this is outer FXML (New.fxml in view package):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="380.0" prefWidth="529.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="controller.NewController">
   <children>
      <fx:include source="NewInside.fxml" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is its controller (NewController.java in controller package):

```
package controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class NewController implements Initializable {

    /*@FXML private Label newLbl;
    @FXML private Button newBtn;
    @FXML private TextField newTxt;
    */

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }

    /*@FXML
    public void btnClick(ActionEvent e){
        newLbl.setText(newTxt.getText());
    }*/

}
```

Finally, this is the Main.java in application package:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/New.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

When I clicked the button, it gives me very long exception:
"Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException....
.....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.NewInsideController.btnClick(NewInsideController.java:27)
    ... 57 more"

Please help me! :(

Comment: I'm just a beginner but just a guess: remove the word static from them FXML variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Inge suggests, using the static field is not the right way to do it. Also, instead of `public`, you should use `private`. If you need to expose your controls, use their properties.

You can read why here:

- You should not use a [static field here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26527018/3956070)
- ... don't use [static fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23109125/3956070)

Just change this in your `NewInsideController`:

```
@FXML private Label newLbl;
@FXML private TextField newTxt;
@FXML private Button newBtn;
```

**EDIT**

If you want to have access to your controls from other classes, instead of adding getters/setters to expose directly the controls, it is better just exposing their properties.

For instance, to have access to the text of these controls you could add:

```
public StringProperty newLblText() { 
    return newLbl.textProperty();
}
public StringProperty newTxtText() { 
    return newTxt.textProperty();
}
public StringProperty newBtnText() { 
    return newBtn.textProperty();
}
```

This will allow you binding (or listening to changes), getting/setting the text property from any of them from the outside of your controller.

To get a valid instance of `NewInsideController` from `NewController`, follow this [link](http://blog.buildpath.de/fxml-composition-how-to-get-the-controller-of-an-included-fxml-view-nested-controllers/). First modify `New.fxml`:

```
<fx:include fx:id="newInside" source="NewInside.fxml" />
```

and now you can get an instance, and add some listeners with those properties:

```
public class NewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Parent newInside;
    @FXML
    private NewInsideController newInsideController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        newInsideController.newBtnText().addListener(
            (obs,s,s1)->System.out.println("nweBtn Text;" +s1));
        if(newInsideController.newLblText().get().isEmpty()){
            newInsideController.newLblText().set("Text for the textfield");
        }
        newInsideController.newTxtText().addListener(
           (obs,s,s1)->System.out.println("s1 "+s1));
    }    
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "If you need to expose your controls, use their properties"? Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Where should I place the last chunk of code into? Is it in controller class?

Comment: The intention of the properties added in NewInsideController is allowing some interaction from an outside class, providing the latter has a valid instance of the former. For instance, let's say that `NewController` needs to set/get some parameters to/from `NewInsideController`. I've edited the answer to clarify this.